# Scraping URLs that are not at plain sight

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am practicing scraping this web page: https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=sabores

It contains the beneficts of Santander related to food, what I want to do is to get the links of the diffent options that are shown, but when I go to the source page I can't found this information.

I have been reading and I understand that you can't hide any information in the source code, but you can "encrypted" some way. I want to know what it is happening in this particular case I am working on, it is "encryted"? or it is something else?

For example, the first product is Work/Café, the URL is: https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/promociones/work-cafe?segmento=s-personas&categoria=sabores
How can I find this URL in the source code? or why I can´t find it

the source code is: [source](http://view-source:https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/todos?segmento=s-personas&categoria=sabores)

Comment: They are using AJAX. Look in the Network tab in the console: https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones.json?limit=5&tags=destacado-cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually get it using the request url and get the json response. It'll return all the promotions and you can access the urls associated in that json format:

```
import requests

url = 'https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/promociones.json'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36'}
params = {
'per_page': '500',
'page': '1'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params = params).json()

promotions = response['promociones']

# This will print ALL promototions
for promo in promotions:
    print (promo['url'])


# To print just a specific category as defined in the json response
for promo in promotions:
if promo['category'] == 'sabores':
    print (promo['url'])
```

**Output:**

```
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/work-cafe
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/le-due-torri-4
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/senz-sushi-nikkei
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/chili-s
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/1756
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/idilico-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/la-celia-restobar
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/au-restaurante
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/ph-banh-mi-by-vietnam-discovery-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/vietnam-discovery-3
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/majestic-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/bozzo-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/tambo-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/boost-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/panko-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/mizu-sushi
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/fork-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/hacienda-patagonia-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/san-marino-puerto-montt-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/toro-bayo-talca
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/burger-club-la-serena-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/vivace-talca-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/cambalache
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/las-vacas-gordas-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/castillo-forestal-2
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/burger-king-3
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/rosa-amelia
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/montana-steak-house-bar
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/zocca
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/club-de-yates-puerto-montt
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/museo-peruano
https://banco.santander.cl/beneficios/sabores/promociones/pf-chang-s-2
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use selenium/web driver.